# Did the reputation cap change for beta sites?

Tags: support, questions, reputation

I noticed last night that I managed to squeak in 200 reputation by about 7:30 EST, beating the 8 PM cut-off time for the new day.  My profile for yesterday shows "200" reputation listed.

Either the system is taking almost 12 hours to hand out `Mortarboard` badges, I didn't truly hit 200 rep, or the reputation cap has increased beyond 200.

So, out of curiosity, *did* the reputation cap increase and I missed the memo, or is there nothing to see here?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It looks like some of your rep came from accepted answers. Accepted answers and bounties don't affect the rep cap; the rep cap is only a cap on how much rep you can get from votes. None of my answers were accepted, so all of my rep came from votes; thus, I got exactly 200 rep and the badge. You probably had less than 200 rep from votes alone.

Comment: That would be the case then, I did have one down vote I forgot about.  198 rep, so close!

Answer (score 1):

It hasn't been changed, I got Mortarboard day 1 here.  The badge showed up pretty quickly after I earned it.